# Accessing AspNetRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I have a global filters which adds a token to the request.Items collection which subsequent filters can also access.

The problem I am having is when trying to get a hold of the request.Items when I am within an injected class.

When trying to access the Items array this injected class using 
`var req = HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest();` my item is no longer available. I have discovered that this is because in the filters, the provided `IRequest.Items` array is a cloned copy of `HttpContext.Current.Items` within an `AspNetRequest` object, so anything I add is not placed into `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

So my question is, how do I access or inject the current `AspNetRequest.Items` array in this situation, or should I just add my item to `HttpContext.Current.Items` directly?

See https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/AspNet/AspNetRequest.cs#L53 for the clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the underlying ASP.NET Request from the `IRequest` with:

```
var aspReq = (HttpRequestPase)req.OriginalRequest;
var item = aspReq.Items["item"];
```

Otherwise you could also use the `HttpContext.Current.Items` singleton.

Comment: Thanks, that covers me setting items from the filter, but is there no-way of me accessing that AspNetRequest from elsewhere?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, IRequest is available everywhere throughout ServiceStack

Comment: So when I retrieve the IRequest in the filter, its an instance of `AspNetRequest`. This is great, and subsequent filters also see this same instance. However, when I retrieve it within one of my injected classes, it appears to be a new instance of `AspNetRequest` which has then lost the Items I added via the IRequest.AddItem extension because they added the item to the previous instance of `AspNetRequest`. It just feels a bit clunky that that data is lost, and not passed through to the underlying HttpContext when I call AddItem.

Comment: @dnolan Its only a new instance of ASP.NET HttpRequestBase if it's a different request, ServiceStack doesn't create instances of ASP.NET underlying HttpContext. If you retrieve it via the singleton then it returns a new instance of IRequest wrapper because it has to, it can't maintain singleton references to same IRequest since it's not ThreadSafe, but it wraps the same underlying ASP.NET HttpRequestBase if it's the same request. If you want the same instance of IRequest, don't get it from the HttpContext singleton, pass it in from the Service's base.Request.