# ServiceStack - SessionAs results in PreAuthenticate being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I have a simple application that registers `JwtAuthProviderReader` as the only `IAuthProvider`. When I attempt to access the session from a service method using `SessionAs` it appears to invoke the `JwtAuthProviderReader PreAuthenticate` again.

I looked through the source code and it would appear that `SessionAs` results in a reference to `IRequest.Items[Keywords.Session]` which is not set, so it invokes the PreAuth filters again.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922776/accessing-aspnetrequest) suggests that I can use `HttpContext.Current.Items` singleton but the session does not exist in there either. How can I get at the session here without invoking PreAuth again?

Answer (score 0):

The `PreAuthenticate` needs to execute in order to be able to access the Users Session attached to the request, in the case for [JWT Auth](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) the partial session is embedded in the JWT Token.

But after the session is retrieved from the JWT Token once it is not invoked again.

You can prevent the Auth Providers `PreAuthenticate()` from being invoked again by setting `Keywords.HasPreAuthenticated` in your `IRequest.Items` Dictionary before retrieving the Session, e.g:

```
httpReq.Items[Keywords.HasPreAuthenticated] = bool.TrueString;
```

> In your Service you can access your IRequest with base.Request

But if you prevent `PreAuthenticate()` from running one time you will not be able to access the Session from the JWT Token.